# Limit google autocomplete to City and Country only iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete

I have implemented the google AutoComplete function to my app. i want to make sure those autocompletes only for Location, Administrative Area and Country. not roads or any other places. can we do that?

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter) {
  /**
   * All results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter,
  /**
   * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
   */
 kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode,
  /**
   * Geocoding results with a precise address.
   */
 kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterAddress,
  /**
   * Business results.
   */
 kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "sublocality"
   * "postal_code",
   * "country",
   * "administrative_area_level_1",
   * "administrative_area_level_2"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "administrative_area_level_3"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity,
};
```

This can be achieve by editing this header file right? but i tried removing some of them. but still works same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a while. i found the solution.

```
 let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter() 
filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City
```

---

Comment: Hii can you give me any solution. i want only state filter not city and country .? Thanks ..

Comment: @YogeshPatel I guess states are comes in to `administrative_area_level_1 ` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Thanks for comment.Yes you're right but how can i achieve that. Please help ?

Answer (score 12):

You could limit the search results

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .City
filter.country = "uk"
```

using the above code to restrict result to UK and only get City results.

Comment: Hii can you give me any solution. i want only state filter not city and country .? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.country = "uk|country:fr|country:us"
```